# Website changed and now scraping with python is not possible

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I used to be able to scrape a table from [www.fangraphs.com](http://www.fangraphs.com) using the following script:

```
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import lxml
import openpyxl

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(start_date,end_date):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a dataframe.
    """
    # parse input
  
    #PITCHERS_URL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=c%2C13%2C7%2C8%2C120%2C121%2C331%2C105%2C111%2C24%2C19%2C14%2C329%2C324%2C45%2C122%2C6%2C42%2C43%2C328%2C330%2C322%2C323%2C326%2C332%2C31%2C30%2C29&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=&startdate={}&enddate={}&page=1_5000&pagenum=1&pageitems=2000000000".format(start_date, end_date)
    PITCHERS_URL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=c,13,7,8,120,121,331,105,111,24,19,14,329,324,45,122,6,42,43,328,330,322,323,326,332,31,30,29&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=&startdate={}&enddate={}&page=1_2000".format(start_date, end_date)   
    # request the data
    pitchers_html = requests.get(PITCHERS_URL).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pitchers_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "rgMasterTable"})
    
    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)
    
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)

def calc_speX(df, IP_limit):
    # A bunch of calculations
    
    return speX

sdate = '2023-03-30'
enddate = '2023-08-17'
IP = 0 
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sdate, date_format)
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(enddate, date_format)

daily = input("Do you want the daily values? ")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('speX-daily.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 

if daily.lower()=="y":
    for single_date in pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date):
        date_str = single_date.strftime(date_format)
        speX = parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(date_str, date_str)
        result = calc_speX(speX, IP)
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=date_str)



writer.save()

writer.close()
```

This is an example of a table I'm still able to fetch with requests:

https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=c,13,7,8,120,121,331,105,111,24,19,14,329,324,45,122,6,42,43,328,330,322,323,326,332,31,30,29&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=&startdate=2023-08-19&enddate=2023-08-19&page=1_2000

(That's a legacy link they are providing for the moment for backwards compatibility with the original link we used to use).

But now, the new version of the leaderboard points to this website:

https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=c%2C13%2C7%2C8%2C120%2C121%2C331%2C105%2C111%2C24%2C19%2C14%2C329%2C324%2C45%2C122%2C6%2C42%2C43%2C328%2C330%2C322%2C323%2C326%2C332%2C31%2C30%2C29&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=&startdate=2023-08-19&enddate=2023-08-19&page=1_2000&pagenum=1&pageitems=2000000000

Which I can't fetch with requests. I also tried selenium to render the dynamic stuff and then tried to use requests but that didn't work either.

(Updating here to share what I tried with selenium:

```
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
chromedriver_path = '/chd/chromedriver.exe' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options) 
driver.get(url) 
time.sleep(5) 
html = driver.page_source 
driver.quit() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") 
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "rgMasterTable"})
```

But table is showing empty.)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It did not work is not a problem that can be solved. What did not work? What you need to do is render the page with selenium and then do source = driver.page_source() and the parse source with something like bs4 to extract the content you want.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply. I did try this with selenium:
         chrome_options = Options()

        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        chromedriver_path = '/chd/chromedriver.exe'
   
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)

        driver.get(url)

        time.sleep(5)

        html = driver.page_source

        driver.quit()        

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")


But it's showing empty.

Comment: Do not put (new) code in comments. You may have noticed that you can't properly format code in comments, that's the sign that code does not belong in comments =) Update your post to talk about everything you tried, and if that includes Selenium, show its code. In 2023 I'd recommend using `playwright`, but that's personal preference. The most important part is that you look at what you're getting back from that URL request, because if the network response says that you're not allowed to scrape this website (through http status codes or page content), then that's the end of that.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and suggestions, I appreciate them. I updated the post to add the code I was missing. As far as I believe, I'm not getting that kind of response from the networks, I could be wrong, though. Could you suggest to me how can I double check that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use BeautifulSoup with Selenium.  The Selenium `page_source` gets you exactly the same text as `requests`.  You EITHER use (requests + BeautifulSoup) or you use Selenium, and then use Selenium's APIs to troll through the DOM.

Comment: That's not true @TimRoberts. I use Selenium to capture a JS rendered version of the page, then use BS4 to extract the content I want. requests only gets you the page source is JS does not build the page further after initial reification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page uses javascript to load the data from different URL in Json form. To load the table into pandas dataframe you can use:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/major-league/data"

params = {
    "age": "",
    "pos": "all",
    "stats": "pit",
    "lg": "all",
    "qual": "0",
    "season": "2021",
    "season1": "2015",
    "startdate": "2023-08-19",
    "enddate": "2023-08-19",
    "month": "1000",
    "team": "0",
    "pageitems": "2000000000",
    "pagenum": "1",
    "ind": "0",
    "rost": "0",
    "players": "",
    "type": "c,13,7,8,120,121,331,105,111,24,19,14,329,324,45,122,6,42,43,328,330,322,323,326,332,31,30,29",
    "sortdir": "default",
    "sortstat": "Balls",
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
   xMLBAMID  season                                                                 Name                                                                                                                                        Team   Age     AgeR    W    L        ERA    G   GS   CG  ShO   SV  HLD   BS   IP   TBF    H    R   ER   HR   BB  IBB  HBP   WP   BK    SO        K/9       BB/9        H/9  K/BB      IFH%  BUH%      TTO%    GB   FB   LD  IFFB  IFH   BU  BUH        K%       BB%     K-BB%     SIERA      HR/9       AVG      WHIP     BABIP      LOB%       FIP     kwERA       E-F      xFIP        ERA-        FIP-       xFIP-     GB/FB       LD%       GB%       FB%     IFFB%     HR/FB    RS       RS/9  Balls  Strikes  Pitches       WPA      -WPA      +WPA    RE24       REW       pLI      inLI    gmLI    exLI  Pulls  Games    WPA/LI    Clutch   SD   MD      FB%1        FBv       SL%        SLv       CT%        CTv       CB%        CBv       CH%        CHv       SF%        SFv  KN%  KNv  XX%   PO%       wFB       wSL       wCT       wCB       wCH       wSF  wKN     wFB/C      wSL/C     wCT/C      wCB/C     wCH/C      wSF/C  wKN/C  O-Swing%  Z-Swing%    Swing%  O-Contact%  Z-Contact%  Contact%     Zone%  F-Strike%    SwStr%     CStr%  C+SwStr%        Q   TG       TIP  PlayerNameRoute       PlayerName  playerid TeamName TeamNameAbb  teamid      tERA       WAR   Dollars  RA9-Wins  Start-IP  Relief-IP       RAR  Starting  Relieving  BIP-Wins  LOB-Wins   BS-Wins  Pull  Cent  Oppo  Soft   Med  Hard  bipCount     Pull%     Cent%     Oppo%     Soft%      Med%     Hard%        K/9+       BB/9+       K/BB+        H/9+       HR/9+        AVG+       WHIP+      BABIP+       LOB%+         K%+        BB%+        LD%+        GB%+        FB%+      HRFB%+      Pull%+      Cent%+      Oppo%+      Soft%+       Med%+      Hard%+   pb_o_CH   pb_s_CH   pb_c_CH   pb_o_CU   pb_s_CU   pb_c_CU   pb_o_FF   pb_s_FF   pb_c_FF   pb_o_SI   pb_s_SI   pb_c_SI   pb_o_SL   pb_s_SL   pb_c_SL   pb_o_KC   pb_s_KC   pb_c_KC   pb_o_FC   pb_s_FC   pb_c_FC   pb_o_FS   pb_s_FS   pb_c_FS  pb_overall  pb_stuff  pb_command  pb_xRV100   pb_ERA  sp_s_CH  sp_l_CH  sp_p_CH  sp_s_CU  sp_l_CU  sp_p_CU  sp_s_FF  sp_l_FF  sp_p_FF  sp_s_SI  sp_l_SI  sp_p_SI  sp_s_SL  sp_l_SL  sp_p_SL  sp_s_KC  sp_l_KC  sp_p_KC  sp_s_FC  sp_l_FC  sp_p_FC  sp_s_FS  sp_l_FS  sp_p_FS  sp_s_FO  sp_l_FO  sp_p_FO    sp_stuff  sp_location  sp_pitching  PPTV  CPTV  BPTV  DSV  DGV  BTV  rPPTV rCPTV  rBPTV  rDSV  rDGV  rBTV  EBV  ESV  rFTeamV  rBTeamV  rTV    pfxFA% pfxFT%    pfxFC%    pfxFS%    pfxFO%    pfxSI%    pfxSL%    pfxCU%    pfxKC%  pfxEP%    pfxCH% pfxSC%  pfxKN% pfxUN%     pfxvFA pfxvFT     pfxvFC  pfxvFS     pfxvFO     pfxvSI     pfxvSL     pfxvCU     pfxvKC  pfxvEP     pfxvCH pfxvSC  pfxvKN   pfxFA-X pfxFT-X   pfxFC-X   pfxFS-X   pfxFO-X    pfxSI-X   pfxSL-X   pfxCU-X   pfxKC-X  pfxEP-X   pfxCH-X pfxSC-X  pfxKN-X    pfxFA-Z pfxFT-Z   pfxFC-Z   pfxFS-Z   pfxFO-Z   pfxSI-Z   pfxSL-Z   pfxCU-Z   pfxKC-Z  pfxEP-Z   pfxCH-Z pfxSC-Z  pfxKN-Z    pfxwFA pfxwFT    pfxwFC    pfxwFS    pfxwFO    pfxwSI    pfxwSL    pfxwCU    pfxwKC  pfxwEP    pfxwCH pfxwSC  pfxwKN  pfxwFA/C pfxwFT/C  pfxwFC/C   pfxwFS/C  pfxwFO/C   pfxwSI/C   pfxwSL/C   pfxwCU/C  pfxwKC/C  pfxwEP/C  pfxwCH/C pfxwSC/C  pfxwKN/C  pfxO-Swing%  pfxZ-Swing%  pfxSwing%  pfxO-Contact%  pfxZ-Contact%  pfxContact%  pfxZone%    pfxPace     piCH% piCS%     piCU%     piFA%     piFC%     piFS% piKN% piSB%     piSI%     piSL%  piXX%      pivCH pivCS      pivCU      pivFA      pivFC      pivFS pivKN pivSB      pivSI      pivSL  pivXX    piCH-X piCS-X    piCU-X    piFA-X    piFC-X    piFS-X piKN-X piSB-X  piSI-X    piSL-X  piXX-X    piCH-Z piCS-Z    piCU-Z    piFA-Z    piFC-Z    piFS-Z piKN-Z piSB-Z    piSI-Z    piSL-Z  piXX-Z     piwCH piwCS     piwCU     piwFA     piwFC     piwFS piwKN piwSB     piwSI     piwSL  piwXX   piwCH/C piwCS/C    piwCU/C   piwFA/C   piwFC/C    piwFS/C piwKN/C piwSB/C   piwSI/C    piwSL/C  piwXX/C  piO-Swing%  piZ-Swing%  piSwing%  piO-Contact%  piZ-Contact%  piContact%   piZone%     piPace  Events         EV         LA  Barrels   Barrel%    maxEV  HardHit  HardHit%
0    518876    2023    <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=11156&position=P">Merrill Kelly</a>  <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=strType&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=15&rost=0&age=0">ARI</a>  34.0  34 - 34  1.0  0.0   5.062500  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.1  23.0  5.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   3.0   5.062500   6.750000   8.437501  0.75  0.000000   0.0  0.391304   8.0  6.0  2.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.130435  0.173913 -0.043478  6.814723  3.375000  0.263158  1.687500  0.214286  0.967742  9.266398  6.731314 -4.203898  6.240479  114.409270  216.769549  142.773045  1.333333  0.125000  0.500000  0.375000  0.000000  0.333333   6.0  10.125001   46.0     56.0    102.0 -0.052730 -0.497390  0.444660 -0.4770 -0.051707  0.974500  1.057333  0.9100  0.6580    1.0    1.0 -0.289987  0.235877  0.0  0.0  0.509804  92.576923  0.039216  86.750000  0.225490  90.913043  0.068627  81.714286  0.156863  88.500000       NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  None  0.883389 -0.744583 -0.320721 -0.109063 -1.114812       NaN  NaN  1.698824 -18.614566 -1.394441  -1.558041 -6.967572        NaN    NaN  0.235294  0.617647  0.362745    0.687500    1.000000  0.864865  0.333333   0.565217  0.049020  0.186275  0.235294  2.66667  2.0  5.333333    Merrill Kelly    Merrill Kelly     11156      ARI         ARI      15  9.508010 -0.180412 -1.443298  0.055214       5.1        NaN -2.236277 -2.236277        NaN  0.084332  0.151295  0.235626   9.0   5.0   2.0   1.0   7.0   8.0      16.0  0.562500  0.312500  0.125000  0.062500  0.437500  0.500000   59.042929  203.658426   28.991156   97.486839  277.280366  105.720997  126.886197   71.965612  134.765090   58.596889  202.119885   60.720855  116.359101  102.898818  258.867473  137.151537   89.859671   51.630435   40.651269   84.323899  152.708810  62.01632  56.11932  58.42567  47.85347  40.28509  53.62588  36.85767  44.25471  41.80059  55.00991  43.04447  68.89373  24.87564  29.35530  47.18540       NaN       NaN       NaN  21.28015  42.33376  43.51832       NaN       NaN       NaN    39.66693  42.11036    51.79774    0.73383  5.42046    101.8    116.0    117.5    123.0    100.3    111.0     82.7     90.7     90.3     94.2    110.6    105.3     82.4     85.8     81.7      NaN      NaN      NaN     79.7     85.7     84.1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   89.724510    97.374510    96.908824   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    NaN  None    NaN  None  None  None  0.0  0.0      0.0      0.0  0.0  0.401961   None  0.176471       NaN       NaN  0.156863  0.039216  0.068627       NaN     NaN  0.156863   None     NaN   None  92.129269   None  90.927775     NaN        NaN  92.824997  86.800003  81.671430        NaN     NaN  88.393753   None     NaN -5.007086    None -1.490211       NaN       NaN -10.056524 -0.089885  3.258131       NaN      NaN -9.551723    None      NaN   8.744617    None  7.440270       NaN       NaN  4.127217  2.624391 -5.055577       NaN      NaN  0.806465    None      NaN -0.604351   None -0.386536       NaN       NaN  1.638759 -0.744583 -0.109063       NaN     NaN -1.165058   None     NaN -1.474028     None -2.147423        NaN       NaN  10.242244 -18.614566  -1.558041       NaN       NaN -7.281614     None       NaN     0.181818     0.574468   0.362745       0.600000       0.962963     0.864865  0.460784  19.294872       NaN  None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  None  None       NaN       NaN    NaN        NaN  None        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  None  None        NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   None   None     NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   None   None       NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN  None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  None  None       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN    None        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN    None    None       NaN        NaN      NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN           NaN           NaN         NaN       NaN  19.294872    16.0  93.471428  11.178416      2.0  0.125000  105.043      9.0  0.562500
1    669947    2023  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19205&position=P">Jesse Scholtens</a>   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=strType&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=4&rost=0&age=0">CHW</a>  29.0  29 - 29  0.0  1.0  15.000000  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  20.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  0.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0   6.000000  15.000000  15.000000  0.40  0.222222   0.0  0.350000   9.0  2.0  2.0   0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.100000  0.250000 -0.150000  7.967662  0.000000  0.333333  3.333333  0.384615  0.500000  6.933064  8.009575  8.066936  8.028816  349.411138  156.603326  187.886573  4.500000  0.153846  0.692308  0.153846  0.000000  0.000000   2.0   6.000000   43.0     43.0     86.0 -0.270212 -0.512980  0.242768 -3.0410 -0.257276  1.134900  0.710133  0.9124  0.5104    1.0    1.0 -0.179357 -0.058736  0.0  0.0  0.465116  92.550000  0.279070  86.041667       NaN        NaN  0.232558  74.850000       NaN        NaN  0.023256  86.500000  NaN  NaN  NaN  None -0.956278 -1.427186       NaN  0.614193       NaN -0.152232  NaN -2.390696  -5.946607       NaN   3.070965       NaN  -7.611594    NaN  0.262295  0.560000  0.348837    0.750000    0.928571  0.833333  0.290698   0.450000  0.058140  0.151163  0.209302  3.00000  1.0  3.000000  Jesse Scholtens  Jesse Scholtens     19205      CHW         CHW       4  5.976011 -0.042589 -0.340714 -0.237644       3.0        NaN -0.450108 -0.450108        NaN -0.082860 -0.112195 -0.195055  10.0   2.0   1.0   0.0   8.0   5.0      13.0  0.769231  0.153846  0.076923  0.000000  0.615385  0.384615   67.629179  461.457081   14.655573  178.335580    0.000000  137.179241  257.252757  131.078415   69.375001   43.171418  294.573376   78.170474  164.793424   40.159784    0.000000  188.602423   44.463104   31.252639    0.000000  118.450285  117.674081  20.00000  31.08769  20.00000  80.00000  50.89183  79.76030  29.17789  39.45867  43.27561       NaN       NaN       NaN  39.66313  44.48733  38.95704       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    38.91493  39.09323    48.85095    0.77915  5.48844     96.3     86.6     63.7     99.8    112.1    116.3     69.6     82.0     76.7      NaN      NaN      NaN     70.5     83.8    105.8      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   77.495349    89.609302    93.727907   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    NaN  None    NaN  None  None  None  0.0  0.0      0.0      0.0  0.0  0.465116   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.279070  0.232558       NaN     NaN  0.023256   None     NaN   None  92.517499   None        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN  85.920837  74.754999        NaN     NaN  86.699997   None     NaN -0.804482    None       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN  2.973824  4.572616       NaN      NaN -4.094846    None      NaN   7.505032    None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.888110 -6.218661       NaN      NaN  4.589387    None      NaN -0.956278   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN -1.427186  0.614193       NaN     NaN -0.152232   None     NaN -2.390696     None       NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN  -5.946608   3.070965       NaN       NaN -7.611594     None       NaN     0.272727     0.483871   0.348837       0.666667       1.000000     0.833333  0.360465  21.757576       NaN  None  0.232558  0.465116       NaN  0.023256  None  None       NaN  0.279070    NaN        NaN  None  75.053455  92.843817        NaN  87.025757  None  None        NaN  86.235738    NaN       NaN   None  4.450641 -0.950269       NaN -4.296225   None   None     NaN  3.020993     NaN       NaN   None -6.813444  7.269569       NaN  3.955085   None   None       NaN  0.253557     NaN       NaN  None  0.614193 -0.956278       NaN -0.152232  None  None       NaN -1.427186    NaN       NaN    None   3.070965 -2.390696       NaN  -7.611594    None    None       NaN  -5.946608      NaN    0.298246    0.448276  0.348837      0.705882      1.000000    0.833333  0.337209  21.757576    13.0  87.132512   3.995001      0.0  0.000000  108.269      3.0  0.230769
2    642547    2023   <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=18679&position=P">Freddy Peralta</a>  <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=strType&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=23&rost=0&age=0">MIL</a>  27.0  27 - 27  1.0  0.0   1.588235  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.2  23.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  11.0  17.470590   3.176471   6.352942  5.50  0.000000   0.0  0.565217   4.0  5.0  1.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.478261  0.086957  0.391304  2.046623  0.000000  0.190476  1.058824  0.400000  0.833333  0.442868  1.513923  1.145368  1.893128   36.372979   10.265548   43.429165  0.800000  0.100000  0.400000  0.500000  0.400000  0.000000   4.0   6.352942   42.0     67.0    109.0  0.220796 -0.294240  0.515036  1.7210  0.178712  1.271700  1.092000  0.9216  0.8504    1.0    1.0  0.190188 -0.016566  0.0  0.0  0.486239  94.547170  0.100917  83.000000       NaN        NaN  0.238532  78.192308  0.174312  88.842105       NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  None  1.042734 -0.170898       NaN  1.320171 -0.077454       NaN  NaN  1.967423  -1.553617       NaN   5.077579 -0.407653        NaN    NaN  0.369863  0.555556  0.431193    0.407407    0.750000  0.553191  0.330275   0.652174  0.192661  0.183486  0.376147  5.66667  1.0  5.666666   Freddy Peralta   Freddy Peralta     18679      MIL         MIL      23 -0.070067  0.410446  3.283569  0.288274       5.2        NaN  3.300197  3.300197        NaN -0.097509 -0.024663 -0.122173   2.0   3.0   5.0   3.0   4.0   3.0      10.0  0.200000  0.300000  0.500000  0.300000  0.400000  0.300000  203.756001   95.839264  212.601811   73.401859    0.000000   76.521864   79.614873  134.335809  116.047715  214.855266  101.059943   48.576684   93.087281  137.198424    0.000000   48.764991   86.265284  206.521741  195.126090   77.096137   91.625286  37.39237  45.84214  40.94673  68.82798  52.75477  59.50500  51.31619  53.18036  41.53227       NaN       NaN       NaN  63.73290  47.76717  64.73489       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    51.59117  48.41180    45.49762    0.01524  4.34257     40.4     87.1     78.8     79.2     97.7    105.4    118.6    104.9    108.3      NaN      NaN      NaN    110.2    104.5    107.8      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   94.722936   100.039450   102.415596   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    NaN  None    NaN  None  None  None  0.0  0.0      0.0      0.0  0.0  0.486239   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.100917  0.238532       NaN     NaN  0.174312   None     NaN   None  94.479243   None        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN  83.081820  78.130770        NaN     NaN  88.763158   None     NaN -4.172707    None       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN  1.603368  1.142637       NaN      NaN -9.301757    None      NaN   8.593540    None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  1.000232 -2.134683       NaN      NaN  3.039437    None      NaN  1.022396   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN -0.170898  1.299832       NaN     NaN -0.077454   None     NaN  1.929048     None       NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN  -1.553617   4.999353       NaN       NaN -0.407653     None       NaN     0.333333     0.600000   0.431193       0.347826       0.750000     0.553191  0.366972  18.302326  0.174312  None  0.238532  0.486239       NaN       NaN  None  None       NaN  0.100917    NaN  88.520958  None  77.862446  94.234799        NaN        NaN  None  None        NaN  82.822210    NaN -8.641174   None  2.067440 -3.334924       NaN       NaN   None   None     NaN  2.708465     NaN  1.640086   None -3.648295  7.902925       NaN       NaN   None   None       NaN -0.472517     NaN -0.077454  None  1.299832  1.022396       NaN       NaN  None  None       NaN -0.170898    NaN -0.407653    None   4.999353  1.929048       NaN        NaN    None    None       NaN  -1.553617      NaN    0.333333    0.600000  0.431193      0.347826      0.750000    0.553191  0.366972  18.302326    10.0  85.079150  27.163834      0.0  0.000000  110.153      3.0  0.300000
3    673540    2023      <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=31838&position=P">Kodai Senga</a>  <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=strType&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=25&rost=0&age=0">NYM</a>  30.0  30 - 30  1.0  0.0   1.285714  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0  24.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   5.0   6.428571   2.571429   2.571429  2.50  0.000000   0.0  0.333333  10.0  7.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.208333  0.083333  0.125000  4.423818  1.285714  0.090909  0.571429  0.062500  1.000000  4.552112  4.709575 -3.266398  4.338597   31.493918  107.024412   99.312015  1.428571  0.000000  0.588235  0.411765  0.142857  0.142857  12.0  15.428571   42.0     55.0     97.0  0.149264 -0.206036  0.355300  2.2410  0.242139  0.641500  0.650629  0.9266  0.0100    1.0    1.0  0.198678  0.034001  0.0  0.0  0.381443  94.000000  0.072165  82.714286  0.371134  90.250000  0.041237  73.000000       NaN        NaN  0.134021  81.307692  NaN  NaN  NaN  None  0.758217  0.894199  2.310079 -1.493270       NaN  0.515555  NaN  2.049236  12.774267  6.416886 -37.331760       NaN   3.965805    NaN  0.238095  0.823529  0.443299    0.666667    0.857143  0.790698  0.350515   0.333333  0.092784  0.123711  0.216495  7.00000  1.0  7.000000      Kodai Senga      Kodai Senga     31838      NYM         NYM      25  2.578725  0.067161  0.537288  0.396263       7.0        NaN  0.688911  0.688911        NaN  0.355814 -0.026712  0.329102   9.0   5.0   3.0   4.0  12.0   1.0      17.0  0.529412  0.294118  0.176471  0.235294  0.705882  0.058824   74.975144   77.584158   96.637187   29.710273  105.630609   36.521799   42.966752   20.989970  139.257259   93.592254   96.849110    0.000000  136.893059  112.986939  110.943202  129.083799   84.573808   72.890027  153.040072  136.052005   17.965743       NaN       NaN       NaN  20.00000  44.83201  20.00000  25.28142  47.03823  28.73916       NaN       NaN       NaN  20.00000  54.38768  21.60914       NaN       NaN       NaN  75.52268  42.33066  80.00000       NaN       NaN       NaN    42.70023  43.99719    59.70262    0.55104  5.14627      NaN      NaN      NaN    152.6     73.7     74.8     88.0     92.0     88.7      NaN      NaN      NaN     82.3     74.2     93.7      NaN      NaN      NaN     98.0    104.5     97.6      NaN      NaN      NaN     74.2    100.8    104.8   91.838144    95.371134    93.468041   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    NaN  None    NaN  None  None  None  0.0  0.0      0.0      0.0  0.0  0.391753   None  0.360825       NaN  0.134021       NaN  0.072165  0.041237       NaN     NaN       NaN   None     NaN   None  93.876317   None  90.157143     NaN  81.315383        NaN  82.642857  72.900002        NaN     NaN        NaN   None     NaN -4.448688    None  0.022350       NaN -4.430744        NaN  0.485575 -0.092415       NaN      NaN       NaN    None      NaN   9.275171    None  6.173301       NaN  1.779266       NaN  2.153625 -4.860649       NaN      NaN       NaN    None      NaN  0.701542   None  2.346416       NaN  0.515555       NaN  0.894199 -1.493270       NaN     NaN       NaN   None     NaN  1.846162     None  6.704046        NaN  3.965805        NaN  12.774267 -37.331759       NaN       NaN       NaN     None       NaN     0.192308     0.733333   0.443299       0.600000       0.848485     0.790698  0.463918  20.958904       NaN  None  0.041237  0.381443  0.371134  0.134021  None  None       NaN  0.072165    NaN        NaN  None  73.409752  94.472359  90.697076  81.819101  None  None        NaN  83.126482    NaN       NaN   None  0.177059 -4.179444  0.370582 -4.037893   None   None     NaN  0.891686     NaN       NaN   None -5.908180  8.368412  5.408354  0.491358   None   None       NaN  1.044956     NaN       NaN  None -1.493270  0.737878  2.310079  0.515555  None  None       NaN  0.894199    NaN       NaN    None -37.331759  1.994266  6.416887   3.965805    None    None       NaN  12.774267      NaN    0.207547    0.727273  0.443299      0.636364      0.843750    0.790698  0.453608  20.958904    17.0  82.120225   2.007102      1.0  0.058824  102.628      4.0  0.235294
4    506433    2023       <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=13074&position=P">Yu Darvish</a>  <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=strType&season=2021&month=1000&season1=2015&ind=0&team=29&rost=0&age=0">SDP</a>  36.0  36 - 36  0.0  1.0   7.200000  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  25.0  9.0  4.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   7.0  12.600000   1.800000  16.200000  7.00  0.000000   0.0  0.320000   3.0  4.0  9.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.280000  0.040000  0.240000  3.364142  0.000000  0.391304  2.000000  0.562500  0.636364  1.666398  3.329575  5.533602  2.981300  172.315077   38.356507   68.295624  0.750000  0.562500  0.187500  0.250000  0.000000  0.000000   1.0   1.800000   37.0     67.0    104.0 -0.206550 -0.520020  0.313470 -2.0319 -0.220260  0.886038  0.731667  0.8700  0.9260    1.0    1.0 -0.230472 -0.002644  0.0  0.0  0.413462  94.581395  0.086538  83.222222  0.250000  88.153846  0.201923  79.904762       NaN        NaN  0.048077  89.600000  NaN  NaN  NaN  None -2.136061 -0.203857  0.450593  1.147057       NaN -0.703335  NaN -4.967584  -2.265074  1.733050   5.462176       NaN -14.066699    NaN  0.310345  0.847826  0.548077    0.611111    0.897436  0.807018  0.442308   0.640000  0.105769  0.096154  0.201923  2.50000  2.0  5.000000       Yu Darvish       Yu Darvish     13074      SDP         SDP      29  5.666642  0.223186  1.785491 -0.073863       5.0        NaN  2.009396  2.009396        NaN -0.352035  0.054986 -0.297049   5.0   6.0   5.0   2.0  10.0   4.0      16.0  0.312500  0.375000  0.312500  0.125000  0.625000  0.250000  146.951281   54.308910  270.584123  187.174719    0.000000  157.202526  150.383632  188.909732   88.618256  125.787992   46.487574  273.243848   43.634663   68.599212    0.000000   76.195298  107.831605  129.076088   81.302537  120.462713   76.354405       NaN       NaN       NaN  80.00000  44.29187  80.00000  55.56054  60.73086  54.37032  57.14636  40.29439  59.57340  71.84229  66.66442  64.21450  52.89839  56.00645  45.15669  34.85480  50.30314  44.05890  56.23511  37.08475  62.97742    63.35896  56.87067    60.68034   -0.69393  3.27882      NaN      NaN      NaN     64.2    113.1    137.5    120.5    107.5    108.8     91.5    119.8    112.8    140.0    117.2    142.6     95.4    101.1    103.9     78.0     95.1    104.0     62.7    113.9     72.7      NaN      NaN      NaN  104.188350   108.618447   112.688350   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    NaN  None    NaN  None  None  None  0.0  0.0      0.0      0.0  0.0  0.201923   None  0.057692  0.048077       NaN  0.211538  0.278846  0.009615  0.192308     NaN       NaN   None     NaN   None  94.795236   None  91.066671    89.5        NaN  94.345459  85.913793  69.400002  80.229999     NaN        NaN   None     NaN -4.890698    None -0.544574 -4.586364       NaN  -8.676056  4.817626  6.026740  4.554482      NaN       NaN    None      NaN  10.046760    None  7.107695  2.532134       NaN  6.580478  1.317725 -9.845751 -5.524685      NaN       NaN    None      NaN -1.242820   None -0.300515 -0.703335       NaN -0.893241  0.547251  0.055725  1.073469     NaN       NaN   None     NaN -5.918189     None -5.008581 -14.066699       NaN  -4.060187   1.887073   5.572546  5.367346       NaN       NaN     None       NaN     0.306122     0.763636   0.548077       0.600000       0.880952     0.807018  0.528846  22.896104       NaN  None  0.182692  0.201923  0.057692  0.048077  None  None  0.211538  0.298077    NaN        NaN  None  79.309063  94.807297  91.067413  89.519183  None  None  94.369451  85.770209    NaN       NaN   None  5.798164 -4.020159  0.458511 -3.879052   None   None -7.8256  5.817561     NaN       NaN   None -7.889084  8.810958  5.862505  1.060944   None   None  5.393959 -0.319088     NaN       NaN  None  0.982495 -1.242820 -0.300515 -0.703335  None  None -0.893241  0.693951    NaN       NaN    None   5.171024 -5.918189 -5.008581 -14.066699    None    None -4.060187   2.238553      NaN    0.313725    0.773585  0.548077      0.625000      0.878049    0.807018  0.509615  22.896104    16.0  91.419128  16.461937      0.0  0.000000  107.393      8.0  0.500000
```